# argument in newenvironment

Tags: environments, minted

I am trying to write a `newenvironment` that would be a wrapper for code layout, using `minted`.

So far, I tried that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}

\newenvironment{codeblock}[1][python]{%
\minted[linenos,frame=lines]{#1}%
}{%
\end{minted}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeblock}[python]
print('Hello world')
\end{codeblock}

\end{document}
```

But I get the following error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
```

I'm not sure to get what's wrong; I read some stuff about passing argument to macro that can be tricky, but I'm not sure to get exactly how it works.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at section 7 of the manual for `minted` and `\newmint`. It has several limitations, however. Note that your attempt cannot work and is not really fixable.

Comment: minted like any verbatim environment can not easily be embedded in another macro, it turns off all normal tex parsing so `\end` is not seen as the usual latex end command, instead verbatim environments look for a specific end string `\end{minted}` here and that is not seen. minted may have a way of being embedded, you'd need to check its documentation but it is all about verbatim environments not a general issue of argument passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minted` package just offers the `\newminted` facility, which has several limitations.

You can profit of the powerful `tcolorbox` package, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\NewTCBListing{codeblock}{O{python}}{%
  %colback=white,colframe=white,
  listing only,
  minted language=#1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeblock}[python]
print('Hello world')
\end{codeblock}

\end{document}
```

Look at the package documentation for customizing the code block appearance.

[image]